# How to remove failure iOS builds in iTunes?Is it possible?

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect

I submitted couple of builds for the same app to iTunes using application loader. So finally build version 1.0.4 was distributed in app store successfully.Previous builds are 1.0.1,1.0.2 & 1.0.3 was failure.Is any way to remove failure builds from iOS builds in iTunes.I have searched lot can't find anything.The below image will explain more clearly.

[image]

> Note:I'm not asking to remove test flight builds.i'm aware of removing
>   it.

Answer (score 1):

No, actually you can't remove builds from itunesconnect, but I wonder why did you changed version number after uploading new build in this case(previous was failed build), you can just change build number. Actually there is no need to delete failed builds if you just changing build numbers, you can find build numbers in Xcode YourTarget->General-> "build" below version number.

Comment: Ya i m aware of the build numbers.Actually version is 1.0 only,see the top of screen shot.1.0.1,1.0.2..,  are build numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to remove the build for iTunes connect it will remain there so no point investing your time behind searching for solution also I am trying to understand why do you even want to remove it on first place so maybe I will be able to give you a idea of the same.